# How can I edit a class File?

Tags: .class-file

I am trying to Edit a dot class File for Markus Persson's game MiniCraft to add a Save button to the game. But I can't Figure out how to edit the class files.

Answer (score 1):

.class is a "compiled" Java file.  You don't edit that file, you would need the Java source.

Comment: How do I get the Java Source? Could I decompile and Copy and Past?!?